# Прием данных с GPS-трекера Teltonika FM1100

Tags: node.js, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема с обменом данными между TCP-сервером и GPS-трекером Teltonika FM1100. TCP-сервер написан на Node.js. Трекер присылает данные в виде двоичных AVL-пакетов. Согласно протоколу AVL устройство сначала присылает свой IMEI, затем сервер должен отослать 01 в ответ в виде **двоичного пакета**, после чего трекер осуществляет пересылку данных о своих координатах и состоянии устройств ввода/вывода на сервер. IMEI устройства приходит на сервер без проблем,в ответ отсылаю 01, но от трекера тишина. Запись в сокет осуществляю так:

```
socket.write(0x01);
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так. В веб-программировании новичок, поэтому желательно ответ "разжевать".

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Санька, а ошибка какая-нибудь прилетает от сервера?

Comment: Нет,никаких ошибок не прилетает.Просто после получения сервером IMEI и отправки единицы обратно трекер молчит

Comment: Я подозреваю что дело в строке socket.write(0x01).Просто с яваскриптом знаком совсем недавно

Comment: Хм, можно поиграться, вроде: socket.write(0x01, 'binary'); socket.write('01', 'binary');

Comment: а вот еще нашел по вашему вопросу: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205759/node-js-send-more-datas

Comment: спасибо,сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Проблема решена:

var buf=new Buffer(1);
buf.writeUInt8(0x01,0);
...
socket.write(buf);

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментария:

---

Для отправки двоичных данных нужно в явном виде создавать буфер и передавать его методу `socket.write`:

```
var buf=new Buffer(1);
buf.writeUInt8(0x01,0);
// ...
socket.write(buf);
```